# Can you use old SSL keystore to import a new certificate with possibly a different private key?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ssl-certificate-renewal

I am importing a new certificate into an old java keystore from a new keystore jks file. I am not sure if the old and the new keystores use the same private key. Will the old keystore work with the new certificate when taking into consideration that I have successfully managed to import the new certificate into it? Or it is just better to delete the old keystore and use just the new keystore instead?